# File API not working with Blob in Google Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-os

I'm writing an extension for Google Chrome where I need to download the images of a page and save them on disk on temporary files. To do this, I make an XMLHttpRequest and use it to download the image. In the callback function, when I have the image in request.response, I request a temporary file from Windows using `window.webkitRequestFileSystem(window.TEMPORARY, 1024 * 1024 * 20, writeImageToFile, errorHandler)`. In the callback function writeImageToFile, I create the FileWriter object and write the blob into it. The file is getting created but I'm not able to find out where it is being created. I need the windows path of the file for the extension. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your purpose, you do not need a virtual file system. Use the [`webkitURL.createObjectURL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.URL.createObjectURL) method to create a URL from a blob:

```
window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(blob);
```

#### Since Chrome 19, you can directly get a `Blob` object using `responseType`:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.responseType = 'blob';
xhr.onload = function() {
    // xhr.response is a Blob
    var url = webkitURL.createObjectURL(xhr.response);
    console.log('URL: ', url);
};
xhr.open('GET', 'http://example.com/favicon.ico');
xhr.send();
```

#### Since Chrome 10, you can get an [`ArrayBuffer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript_typed_arrays/ArrayBuffer) response, and convert it to a blob ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5SBnq/)):

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
xhr.onload = function() {
    // Create blob from arraybuffer
    var bb = new (window.BlobBuilder || window.WebKitBlobBuilder)();
    bb.append(xhr.response);
    var url = webkitURL.createObjectURL(bb.getBlob());
    console.log('URL: ', url);
};
xhr.open('GET', 'http://example.com/favicon.ico');
xhr.send();
```

(Use `window.URL` and `MozBlobBuilder` if you want to use the same code for Firefox).

Comment: PS. If you still want to create filesystem URIs, see http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/#toc-filesystemurls

Comment: The data of the image needs to be passed to an NPAPI DLL. Either I should be able to get the image data (base64) in the JavaScript and that passed to the NPAPI DLL directly, or the image saved in a local file, and the path of that file being passed to the NPAPI. The URL created by createObjectURL is only visible to Chrome, not to the NPAPI.

Comment: @RahulGulati base64: `var base64_string = btoa(xhr.responseText);`  (using [`window.btoa`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.btoa)).

Comment: Looks like getting the image data and expanding it inline won't work as the size of images can be pretty large. Is there a way I could save the image on a file and pass the path of the file to the NPAPI DLL, where the path should be accessible to NPAPI DLL?

Comment: @RahulGulati The filesystem created using the File API is **virtual**. AFAIK, there's direct relation between a virtual file in this file system, and the corresponding physical file (located at <chrome profile directory>/Default/File System). Do you really need the physical path of the file for the NPAPI?

Comment: 1. Yes, I need the physical path of the file. I've tried to create files with the extension .tmp in the JavaScript, but they are not showing up in physical memory because of the reason you mentioned. Is there a link that explains the direct relationship between the virtual system, and the physical file system, if there's one such relationship. 
2. Are you sure btoa works for Chrome? I've tried using btoa and window.btoa, but they seem to throw up the following error: Uncaught Error: INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR: DOM Exception 5

Comment: @RahulGulati 1. There might be a relationship (Chrome somehow has to show the right file in JS), but I'm not aware of it. 2. `btoa` works fine, **provided** that the input is ASCII. When at least one charact is outside the `0x00 - 0xff` character range, an error is thrown. Use the `arraybuffer` response type, and wrap it in a [`Uint8Array()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript_typed_arrays/Uint8Array). Then loop through the bytes, and concatenate it. Finally, run [`btoa`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.btoa) on the concatenated string.

Comment: Got the base64 data of the image using the above method. Many thanks!

Comment: @RahulGulati Where exactely are you stuck? It might be useful to post a new question.